# Is there a wiki that works with Aloha editor (or hallo-js)?

Tags: wiki, contenteditable, aloha-editor, hallo-js

I have a dokuwiki wiki set up on my server, and I would love to be able to edit the wiki with inline editing, a la Aloha Editor or Hallo Editor. On the Aloha editor home page they mention that you could use it for wikis in passing, but there are no more details.

I know I could go through all the work of implementing Aloha or Hallo or another similar editor with my dokuwiki setup, but I guess what I'm really wondering is if anyone has already done this with any wiki (dokuwiki or something else).

The end result I'm looking for is: you go to a wiki page, click on the content, edit it in place with Aloha editor or the like, and the new content is saved back to the server. It would allow creating new wiki pages by inserting links to the not-yet-created page (either by clicking the link button or by typing, e.g. [[new-page-link]].

Does this exist in some form somewhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible (or acceptable?) to bump a question? I'd offer a bounty but I don't have enough to offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WYSIWYG Wiki](http://wysiwygwiki.org/), which is written in PHP.

Comment: Wow, looks very promising. I'm impressed with what I see. However, it looks more like it makes it easy to edit a web page than to use as a real wiki (e.g., making a link doesn't create a new page with that link, and there is no way I can see to create new pages). I also realize it is in beta so maybe these things are planned, but there is precious little information about it or who makes it and nowhere to ask questions other than emailing the author. Do you have any other info about it? (Or maybe you're the author...?) Anyway, THANKS a million for this link!

Comment: No, I don't know anything about it, sorry.

Comment: Ok, well thanks anyway. It does a good deal of what I'm looking for and it will help a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you could try https://wikidocs.com. It is based on Aloha Editor (although the controls look different) and even offers collaborative editing of the same page by multiple users.

I think this does exactly what you are searching for.

Comment: This looks interesting, but I'm looking for something I can install on my own server preferably. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The project is not available any more.